# Condition statement in C#7

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, c#-7.0

i want to avoid following writing style.
pointed out simply out of range should be written once

```
var a = 100;   // valid range 1..100_000 int32
var b = 10_000; // valid range 100..30_000_000 int32

if( a <= 1000)
{
    // avoid overflow
    if( b < a * 100)
    {
       // both out of range
    }
}
else if( b < 100_000)
{
    // both out of range
}
```

came up with following style, doesn't fit at first glance...

```
if( a <= 1000 ? b < a * 100 : b < 100_000)
{
    // both out of range
}
```

switch statement? not good...

```
var lessEqual1000 = "a <= 1000";
var greater1000 = "a > 1000";
switch( a <= 1000 ? lessEqual1000 : greater1000)
{
case lessEqual1000 when b < a* 100:
case greater1000 when b < 100_000:
    // both out of range
}
```

what is the best?

======================================

Boss showed me his answer.
ceratainly it looks better.

```
if( b < (a < 1000 ? a * 100 : 100_000))
{
    // both out of range
}
```

in addition to that, without overflow it shold be following.

```
if( b < Math.Min( a * 100, 100_000))
{
  // both out of range
}

// following style hit upon me...
if( b < Math.Min(Math.BigMul(100, a), 100_000))
{
    // both out of range
}
```

where can i sutdy well styled code in c#?...

Comment: Can you provide a table of values and expected result?

Comment: Put it simply,  it's a b's validation of the lower limit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want something along the lines of this, combining the two branches in one statement?

```
if ((a <= 1000 && b < a * 100) || (a > 1000 && b < 100_000)) {
  // Out of range branch
} else {
  // In range branch
}
```

Comment: thank you for your opinion. but it has a bad condition.
b < 100_000 match without variable a condition.